# website login integration with phpBB3

Tags: php, phpbb3

On my site I have a login box that I would like to link to my phpbb3 forum. So that if anyone logged in on the main site they would stay logged in if they went to the forum and vise-versa.

I dont want to use `action="forum/ucp.php?mode=login"` in my login page due some reason.

I added the following code in my login page after my login validations

```
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($row);
//syntax of login call in phpbb/include/functions file 
//$auth->login($username, $password, $autologin, $viewonline, $admin);
$result = $auth->login($_REQUEST['login_username'], $_REQUEST['login_password'], 1, 1, 0);
$user->setup();
```

Its working fine on my local machine. but its giving me following error on the server.

```
SQL ERROR [ mysql4 ]

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3 [1064]
```

Pls help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use print_r() method with $result variable and die immediate. Check whether user has been logged in or not.

Comment: Tried print_r(), but the same error.

Comment: Try to print both request variable. I also used the same concept and never get any error.

Comment: Can you show us a snippet of the SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Arjun for your tips. after debugging I found problem in my `$row`,

`$auth->acl()` required the associative array and I am passing Object array.

Sorry for my stupid mistake & thanks all for your help..